# Is it possible to map strings obtained by a macro, which contain XML tags, to existing Word styles?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros, styles

From a macro, I'm obtaining a string like the following:

```
<p>D. W. Arning et al. <i>Mixed Mode–Mixed level Circuit Simulator</i>. (2011). Ngspice. [Online]. Available: http:..., Accessed: Jan. 11, 2019.</p>
```

The content in the *i* tag (and possibly more tags) should be rendered using an existing Word style.

Is it possible to automatically subject such an XML-String to Word styles (ideally mapping *i* tags to *MyStyleName*), and if so, how? Or do I need to manually parse the string using VBA string functions?

Answer (score 0):

This vba is just an example of manually parsing the string. Just selects the string between two tags like `<i>` and `</i>`, and sets the style:

```
Sub setStyle()
' setStyle Macro
Dim MyTags()
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
MyTags() = Array("<i>", "</i>")

' get first tag
Set r1 = ActiveDocument.Range
With r1.Find
   .ClearFormatting
   .Execute Findtext:=MyTags(0), Forward:=True
End With

' get second tag
Set r2 = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=r1.End, End:=ActiveDocument.Range.End)
With r2.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = MyTags(1)
    .Execute
End With

' select text between tags
ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=r1.End, End:=r2.Start).Select

' set selection to named Style
Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Intense Emphasis")
End Sub
```

If your source documents are just markdown-formatted instead of xml/html, then there are converters like pandoc